# Is it possible to hide unity's panel on a second monitor?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, panel

I'm using v3.8. Curious if it is possible in 4.x ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the top panel: no, that's not possible. The launcher bar on the left side should only be on the primary monitor and hide wrt. to your launcher hide settings in the CompizConfig Setting Manager (`ccsm`).

Comment: Not even in 4.x? Was there a bug reported on this subject?

Comment: I have submitted a bug. If anyone wants to vote for an option to hide the top panel on a certain monitor, this is the link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/853865